How to change only Taskbar color in Kubuntu 24.04 (Plasma 5.27.11)?
After recently installing Kubuntu 24.04 (Plasma 5.27.11), I would like to have the Taskbar use colors similar to Breeze-Dark, while the rest of the UI remains similar to Breeze-Light. Is this possible?
I have tried editing the color scheme in system settings, and have also mucked around with color files like those under /usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/, to no avail.
As far as I can tell, the Taskbar color is controlled by the color Window Normal Background, making it impossible to separate window and taskbar colors.
Perhaps editing one of the myriad of SVG files of the theme can save the day? But it is hard to tell which might do the trick.
Prefer a canonical solution, but a hack will also do the trick. Any ideas?

After some more experimenting, here is a partial answer to my own question.
I was eventually able to achieve the desired behavior of dark taskbar on light UI by choosing:
Global Theme: Breeze
Plasma Style: Breeze Dark
Color Scheme: Breeze Light
It was pretty easy, so maybe this was a bad question.
However, I feel it was somewhat lucky that this trick existed, and it would not have worked to achieve a different color taskbar. I also do not understand why this random combination of style settings melded to give the result.
So a more insightful answer on how to customize the taskbar color would be very welcome, and I leave the question open.
